# Как вывести старую цену товара по определенному айди?

Tags: modx, minishop2

Делаю магазин на ModX minishop2 + msMiniCartDynamics, и мне нужно вывести старую цену товара, но в msMiniCartDynamics предусмотрен только плейсхолдер цены, а плейсхолдера старой цены нет( Как вывести старую цену товара по определенному айди?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение через Fenom. Нужно создать дополнительное TV поле, туда дублировать старую цену

код ниже высчитывает общую скидку для одного товара

```
{$id_d | resource: "old_price" * $count_d}
```